# Getting this error Premature end of file

Tags: java, xml, soap

I am facing the problem of Premature end of file but not all the time only sometimes am facing this issue. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
while ((responseString = in.readLine()) != null) {
            outputString = outputString + responseString;
         }
 if (outputString != null && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(outputString)) 
         {
            Document document = parseXmlFile(outputString);
            String userName = document.getElementsByTagName("UserID").item(0).getTextContent();
            if(!userName.equalsIgnoreCase("")&&userName!=null&&userName.equalsIgnoreCase(deptUserId))
            {
              String signbaseData = document.getElementsByTagName("Sign").item(0).getTextContent();
              if(signbaseData!=null&&!"".equalsIgnoreCase(signbaseData)) 
              {
                signData=new Base64().decodeBase64(signbaseData.getBytes());
              }
            }
        }
```

this is the parseXMLFile

```
public Document parseXmlFile(String in) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(in));
        return db.parse(is);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
```

}
    }

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check that your files aren't corrupted sometimes?

Comment: how to check whether the file is corrupted or not?

Comment: For example: when hitting the problem ... you open the file and check its content. Or, when it happens at a customer: simply read the complete file as text; and dump contents into your log file.